# Why is my django core.serializers so slow

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-serializer

I have my a serializer from core.serializers in my django view. It does work, but it sometimes takes over 1 minute to show my results table. Any ideas how to get it faster?

```
# views.py 
from django.core import serializers

def search_institution(request):
    form = SearchInstitutionsForm()
    qs = Institution.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchInstitutionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if cd['name']:
                qs = Institution.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'])
            print(f"Before requesting from db: {datetime.now()}")
            print(f"After requesting from db, before serializing: {datetime.now()}")
        context = {
            "result_data": SafeString(serializers.serialize("json", qs)),
            'form': form
        }
        print(f"After serializing, before rendering: {datetime.now()}")
        return render(request, "landing/result_table.html", context)
    else:

        context = {
            "form": SearchInstitutionsForm
        }
        return render(request, "stakeholders/institution_form.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statements don't help much because [Querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). It means they are not evaluated at time of filtering `qs = Institution.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'])` but rather when the actual value is used.

So I'm not going much into serialization there are really nice ways of doing that, and Django on it's own provides good tools already.
Look into Queryset and [database performance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/optimization/), it's the most essential topic, where I suspect your performance issue comes from. Also do more research on select_related and prefetch_related, it will help you reduce 200+ queries to 2

You can use [django Debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) in your local environment to easily monitor your application. But there are other profiling tools and tips too.